# Why isn't localStorage persisting in this RiotJS code

Tags: javascript, riot.js

This is the code:

```
<todo>
  <form onsubmit={ handleSubmit }>
  </form>

  this.items = []

  handleSubmit(e) {
    var input = e.target[0]
    this.items.push(input.value)
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(this.items))
    input.value = ''
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('todos'))
  }
</todo>
```

`console.log(localStorage.getItem('todos'))` does show the key and values (e.g. `["one", "two]`) but then both key and value disappear when I refresh the page.

How to make it persist after page refresh?

Comment: @VonC Oh, ha. Because it was a stupid mistake. Had to use ` ` instead of "". Wanted to avoid public embarrassment. But never mind, I opened it again.